# How to change paragraph parameters in a page

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a text and I would like to quote a long text from some outer source. For that I would like to have the quotet text:

1) slightly smaller, and more important:
2) with bigger margins (so smaller text width).

I tried to use the \parbox command, but there is an issue: it place the box on a new page, while I would like to have it starting exactly where I place it.

How can I do that?

Comment: `\begin{quotation}\small <text to quote>\end{quotation}`?

Comment: latex is so nice: I wanted to quote... and there is the ambient quotation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX has a standard `quotation` environment, so

```
\begin{quotation}\small
Text of the quotation
\end{quotation}
```

will do. However, if you have several of these quotations, I suggest defining a specific environment in the document preamble

```
\newenvironment{doquotation}
 {\begin{quotation}\small}
 {\end{quotation}}
```

Using `doquotation` (or any name you like) as before

```
\begin{doquotation}
Text of the quotation
\end{doquotation}
```

will guarantee you don't forget `\small` and also that changing all quotations to `\footnotesize` just requires modifying the definition and not all quotations.